# Creating a master lists of a bunch of seperate lists in Python

Tags: python, list, pypdf

I have scraped text data from a PDF and used split to divide it into separate pages which I append to an empty list called pages.  However, this results in pages being a object that just contains a whole bunch of separate list objects for each page.

What I want is a master list that contains all of these separate list objects so that when I check for print(type(pages)) I get one list instead of a long printout of individual lists.

```
    #  creating a pdf File object of original pdf 
    pdfFileObj = open(origFileName, 'rb')  
    # creating a pdf Reader object 
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

    numPages = pdfReader.numPages

    for p in range(pdfReader.numPages): 

        # creating page object 
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(p)
        #extract txt from pageObj into unicode string object
        pages = list()
        for x in (pageObj.extractText()).split('\n'): pages.append(x)

        print(pages)
```

The result is very long but a sample looks like:

```
['DESCRIPTIONSULTLetter Type: PLFile Set: SHPPL20190827']
["Dear A**** P***** ,This letter is to let you know that SING DY UY will no longer provide STAR MRSA services for *******HealthPlan effective . This means that SING DY UY cannot be your provider any more through Superior. You can pick a new provider from the ******* HealthPlan network to get services.Superior will work with you to make sure you get the care you need. There is a provider in your areawho can provide services to you. That provider is JOSE BENIGNO JR. You can call them at1-***-362-2685."]
['Estimado(a) ****** *****,Le enviamos esta carta para informarle que SING DY UY dejar de ofrecer servicios de STAR MRSApara ******* HealthPlan a partir del . Esto significa que SING DY UY ya no podr ser su proveedor atravs de Superior. Para obtener servicios, puede escoger un nuevo proveedor de la red de S****** HealthPlan.Superior trabajar con usted para garantizar que reciba la atencin que necesita. Hay un proveedor ensu rea que puede ofrecerle servicios. Ese proveedor es **** BENIGNO JR. Puede comunicarse al1-432-362-2685.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't very clear, but what I've done is made a list called `pages`, and for each page we iterate through, we add the list of lines (called `page` now) to the list of pages.

```
pdfFileObj = open(origFileName, 'rb')  
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 
numPages = pdfReader.numPages
pages = []

for p in range(pdfReader.numPages): 

    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(p)
    page = list()
    for x in pageObj.extractText().split('\n'): 
            page.append(x)
    pages.append(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to append `pages` to your master list. Change your `for` loop to the following, and it should work.

```
master_lst = list()
for p in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(p)
    pages = list()
    for x in pageObj.extractText().split('\n'):
        pages.append(x)
    master_lst.append(pages)
```

However, this code isn't Pythonic. The inner (nested) `for` loop is redundant, because `pageObj.extractText().split('\n')` returns a list of strings, so there's no need to iterate through it.

```
master_lst = list()
for p in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pages = pdfReader.getPage(p).extractText().split('\n')
    master_lst.append(pages)
```

Actually, this block can be replaced by a single line of code. Use list comprehension.

```
master_lst = [pdfReader.getPage(p).extractText().split('\n')
              for p in range(pdfReader.numPages)]
```

The complete code would be as follows.

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open(origFileName, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
numPages = pdfReader.numPages

master_lst = [pdfReader.getPage(p).extractText().split('\n')
              for p in range(pdfReader.numPages)]
```

If you are unfamiliar with list comprehensions, I suggest reading about it here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed

Comment: I'm now having trouble splitting each pages into its separate words.  I either get my original problem of each page plit but now loosing the structure of being in the master list. `for page in pages:
       for line in page:
            words = line.split(" ")
            print(words)`  Or I use list comprehension and it does the same thing but just puts and extra bracket around each seperate list `for page in pages:
            words = [line.split(" ") for line in page]`

Comment: @BenSmith Look up list comprehensions. It will really help you get a clearer picture of what you can do.